# Flash Programming Local To Global problem

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I've got this weird problem and i just cant figure it out.
I'm using the localToGlobal to get the coordinates for my character and do a hittestpoint on a level clip. Everything works fine in flash player 10.1. r52

But then i open the exact same .swf on a other machine running flash player 10.0 r22, and the hittesting doesnt work. I tried everything, tracing the parents etc.

The setup:

Main Class, in Main Class i add a Game class(Sprite).
In the Game Class i add a Level Class(Sprite) and a Character Class(Sprite)

the 'camera' follows the character, and the Game class is moved arround.

So

Main (static x & y)>
Game (dynamic x & y)>
Level(static x & y) & Character (dynamic x & y)
this is my code:

```
    private function checkLanded():Boolean
    {//this code runs on the character class, so 'this' = character
        var localPoint:Point = new Point(this.x, this.y + this.myHeight / 2 + 1);
        var globalPoint:Point = parent.localToGlobal(localPoint)

        if (Settings.levelGround.hitTestPoint(globalPoint.x,globalPoint.y,true) || Settings.levelPlatforms.hitTestPoint(globalPoint.x,globalPoint.y,true))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

So this code runs perfectly in flash player 10.1 but not in 10.0
Now for 10.0, instead of using parent.globalToLocal, i tried parent.parent.globalToLocal which does work in 10.0 and not in 10.1.

How can i make sure that this code will run in all flash players.

****edit-
I fixed it, i moved the main class arround which somehow disturbed the flash coordinate system. I then tryed moving the game class arround and that seem to work. Still wondering why moving the main class arround doesnt work..

---

Please help me,

Thanks in advance,

Erik Sombroek

Comment: why are you using parent at all?  If Character is an descendant of Sprite then it has `localToGlobal` itself.

Comment: @shanethehat Yes i know, but even using
var globalPoint:Point = this.localToGlobal(new Point(0,0)) i have the same result

Comment: you can use backticks to highlight code in comments :)

Comment: @shanethehat, even when im using var `localPoint:Point = new Point(this.x+parent.parent.x,this.y+parent.parent.y + this.myHeight / 2); var globalPoint:Point = localPoint; –` (lol i figured it out haha)

Comment: What is `Settings.levelGround`, and where does it fit in the display tree as you list it in the question?

Comment: Settings is a class where i store the globals. Settings.levelGround references to a Sprite which is also added in the Game object

Answer (score 0):

this is a way to know the coordinates of a display object in reference to the stage

```
public function getDisplayObjectsRootCoord(target:DisplayObject):Point{
    var coords:Point = target.localToGlobal(new Point());
    return coords;
}
```

or to see if the mouse is over an item...

```
var target:MovieClip;
var stage:Stage;// make sure you have a reference to this
var mouseOverPanel:Boolean = target.hitTestPoint(stage.mouseX,stage.mouseY,true);
```